# Error in debug log though class compiled correctly

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch, update

I have below batch class which compiles correctly but throws error runtime says expecting colon

Error:

> FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: expecting a colon, found '('
>
> Class.AckCallUpdate.start: line 4, column 1

**Batch class:**

```
global class AckCallUpdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Account_vod__c,Call_Date_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__c where ESR_Call__c=null and Recordtype.Name like (%Sample%) and Status_vod__c in (Submitted_vod)';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Call2_vod__c> scope) {
         for(Call2_vod__c a : scope)
         {
           List<Call2_vod__c> AckCall= 
            [SELECT Name, Ack_For_Call_abv__c,  
                     Owner.Name FROM Call2_vod__c
                     where Ack_For_Call_abv__c=:a.Name and recordtype.Name like '%Acknowledge%'];

                     //Date d=a.Call_Date_vod__c+90;

                for (Call2_vod__c c : AckCall)
                { if(c.Ack_For_Call_abv__c!=a.Name && a.Call_Date_vod__c+90==date.today())
                  //Check Call date
                 { //if(a.Call_Date_vod__c+90=date.today())
                    a.ESR_Call__c=true;
                }

                }
         }
            update scope;
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }

 }
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is `Submitted_vod` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is coming from the dynamic SOQL string:

```
String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Account_vod__c,Call_Date_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__c where ESR_Call__c=null and Recordtype.Name like (%Sample%) and Status_vod__c in (Submitted_vod)';
```

It is telling you that at runtime the query is invalid and expects a semi-colon but found a (.

It works on compile because the string is valid.

It expects the : because I assume submitted_vod  are variables in the class? if so you would do something like:

```
String query = 'SELECT Id,Name,Account_vod__c,Call_Date_vod__c FROM Call2_vod__c where ESR_Call__c=null and Recordtype.Name like \'%Sample%\' and Status_vod__c in :Submitted_vod';
```